# Why Octave doesn't see this object?

Tags: function, matlab, octave

I wanted to code a function in octave, however I found some problems during doing so:

```
N=700;
T=900;
lambda=N/T;

x=randn(N,T);
s=std(x(:));
r=x*x'/T;
l=eig(r);
lambda_plus=(s^2)*(1+sqrt(lambda))^2;
lambda_minus=(s^2)*(1-sqrt(lambda))^2;

# Define a function - value of this function depenends
# on position of x
function kiki = avg (x)
  if (x <= lambda_plus && x >= lambda_minus)
    (1/(2*pi*lambda*x*s^(2)))*sqrt((lambda_plus-x)*(x-lambda_minus));
  else 
      0
  endif
endfunction
```

Then I wanted to run this function so I did run `avg(2)` but it didn't work.

Error I saw was:

```
error: 'lambda_plus' undefined near line 15, column 15
```

but it's not true! `lambda_plus` is defined before the definition of the function!

I read that this problem might be, because octave doesn't see our function and the solution is to:

(1) Save the file with name of the function - in my case avg.m

(2) Open a new file and in new file run your function

I did exactly what they were saying and in newly created file I ran `avg(2)` but unfortunately with exactly same result.

Comment: Not to sure about Octave but in MATLAB the scope of `lambda_plus` and `lambda_minus` is within the local script and does not extend to the function `avg()` I believe. I tend to compute anything the function needs within the function or pass it as inputs.

Comment: What Michael said. Functions have their own scope and don’t see variables that exist in other scopes, such as the scope of the caller. There are only two exceptions: anonymous functions (lambdas) capture the value of variables in the parent scope, and nested functions have access to the parent scope also. I recommend you read the docs around these concepts to learn more.

Comment: You were right! Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Also, your function is not assigning to its ostensible return value